# Augeas not reading all yum.repos.d files. Why?

Tags: yum

I'm trying to use Augeas to manage some options in yum.repos.d but it's not reading all repo files in there.

Any hint?

```
# ls -l /etc/yum.repos.d/
total 24
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  200 Nov 10 15:50 3rd.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  279 Sep 10 14:21 Citrix.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  172 Nov 10 16:17 epel.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  172 Nov 10 15:21 ius.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1308 Nov 10 15:21 os.repo
```

And in augtool:

```
# augtool ls /files/etc/yum.repos.d/
os.repo/ = (none)
Citrix.repo/ = (none)
```

Trying to debug in augtool:

```
# augtool ls /augeas/files/etc/yum.repos.d/
os.repo/ = (none)
Citrix.repo/ = (none)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found that the not-loaded repo files had `gpgkey=` (without value) inside, and this was preventing `augeas` from loading them.

However, Augeas did not issue any errors. I had to find out myself.

Answer (score 0):

Load errors can be found under `/augeas//error`. However, there used to be a bug where these kinds of errors where not reported in versions 0.7.2 and 0.7.3, which are shipped by default with quite a few versions of RedHat. This bug is now fixed and new versions of Augeas should report load errors properly.